# Route is not a component. All component children of Routes must be a Route or React.Fragment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

This is my App.js file, and I am trying to create some paths but I keep getting an error even after wrapping a Route element around my IsUserRedirect.

```
import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
import * as ROUTES from './constants/routes';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Browse, Home, Signin, Signup } from './pages';
import {IsUserRedirect, ProtectedRoute} from './helpers/routes';
import { useAuthListener } from './hooks';

function App() {

  const { user } = useAuthListener();

  return (
    <>
    <Router>
      
       <Routes>

            <Route>
              <IsUserRedirect user={user} loggedInPath={ROUTES.BROWSE} path={ROUTES.SIGN_IN}>
                  <Signin />
              </IsUserRedirect>
            </Route>     

            <Route>
              <IsUserRedirect user={user} loggedInPath={ROUTES.BROWSE} path={ROUTES.SIGN_UP}>
                  <Signup />
              </IsUserRedirect>  
            </Route>

            <Route>
              <ProtectedRoute user={user} path={ROUTES.BROWSE}>
                  <Browse />
              </ProtectedRoute>              
            </Route>

            <Route>
              <IsUserRedirect user={user} loggedInPath={ROUTES.BROWSE} path={ROUTES.HOME}>
                  <Home />
              </IsUserRedirect>              
            </Route>          


        </Routes>      
      </Router>   
    </>
  );

}

export default App;
```

Since my react-dom version is above v6, I tried to wrap my  into  elements. However,  I am still getting this error:

```
<Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>.
[IsUserRedirect] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>.
```

Answer (score 2):

In React Router v6 onwards, JSX elements has to be inside the Route attribute (`<Route element={<CustomComponent />} />`) and not as a child.
If `IsUserRedirect` inside does not have a `<Route/>` then it will give an error.

Check the documentation:
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/overview#nested-routes